# Position from a Velocity-Time graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, integration, calculus

[image: Graph]

Find the position at t= 3.0 seconds.

The initial position is 2.3 m.

I found the average velocity to be 3.33 repeating so I multiplied that by the time (3) to get 10 and then added the initial position to get 12.3 m but the answer is wrong.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "simply" calculate the average velocity from the velocity at the end points, unless the velocity graph is a straight line. Which it is between 2 and 3. But not between 0 and 3.

So the approach you can take is this:

What is the distance after 2 seconds of moving at 4 m/s?

And what is the average velocity between t=2 and t=3 seconds (straight line - valid approximation)? It is the velocity at 2.5 seconds, of course.

So you have 2 seconds at 4 m/s, and 1 second at, on average, 3 m/s. And then you add them to the initial position.

Answer (score 0):

The final position will be the initial position plus the area under the velocity versus time graph. That is the area between y =0 and the velocity function. I'm assuming you're not familiar with integral calculus, but if you look at the dimensions you arrive at by calculating this area you will find that it is meters. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**By simple calculus:**

Between $t=2s$ and $t=4s$, $v_x$ can be described by the function:

$v_x=8-2t$.

The definition of $v_x$ is:

$v_x=\frac{dx}{dt}$, so that $dx=v_xdt$.

Integrating between $t=2$ and $t=3$ we get the distance travelled in that interval:

$x=\int_2^3(8-2t)dt=3m$.

Add to this the $8m$ travelled in the first $2s$, so total distance is $11m$. Add the initial position of $2.3m$ to get $13.3m$.

Comment: Little trouble with the integral there... $(8t - t^2)$ between 2 and 3 is 24-9-(16-4)=3 not 2.

Answer (score -1):

Note that it is one dimensional motion. At the end of 2 sec, a force (break) is applied, causing a change of velocity of 4 units in 2 sec which means a decceleration of 2 m/s^2. Decceleration is constant since the Vx vs t graph is a st line. You can use use the appropriate equations to find the displacement in the first sec after the application of the breaks. This, added to the displacement at the end of 2 seconds (with constant velocity of 4m/s), gives the displacement at the end of a period of 3 sec. If you know the initial position you can calculate the final position, otherwise, what you can calculate is only the change in position (ie, the displacement), but not the final position at the end of 3 sec.

Initial position of 2.3 m gives a value for displacement from an unknown/unspecified origin but not the initial position.

P. Radhakrishnamurty

Answer (score -1):

Simply, if the *initial position is at 2.3 m*, and one travels for *2 seconds at a rate of $4\frac{m}{s}$*, then the total distance traveled in those two seconds is *8m* (2*4). The position now, after 2 seconds is *8m + 2.3m, which equals to 10.3m*.

In the last second, we see that the slope is negative, which means that one is *decelerating for 1 second*, as it is a velocity-time graph. To find the deceleration, one needs to use the formula *change in velocity/time*. In this case it is *(4-2)/1*, which equals to *-2{m}{s^2}*. So, the *final position is 2 + 10.3*, which equals to $\underline{13.3m}$.

Comment: You apparently mistook the asterisk (symbol *) for the dollar ($) for denoting mathjax at places in your answer.